# How to execute procedures and can macros be included in a tcl script

Tags: tcl

I came across the following program in a profile today....... its a good one written with great intellect.... however I was not able to run it.......

```
proc parseFileContents {contents infoVar} { 
    upvar 1 $infoVar inf 
    set lineNum 0 
    foreach line [split $contents "\n"] {  
       incr lineNum         # Skip comment lines (?) 
       if {[string match {$*} $line} continue         # Skip blank lines 
       if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue        # Parse a "real" line    
       if {[scan $line "%s%s%s%s%s%s%f%f%s%s" a b c name d e value f g h] == 10} {             
           set inf($name) $value
       } else { 
           # Oh dear, didn't work!
           puts "warning: did not understand line $lineNum\n$line"
       }
    } 
}
```

Using it:

```
parseFileContents $theContentsOfTheFile data 
puts "Keys: [array names data]" 
puts "VSS: $data(vss)" puts "VCC: $data(vcc)"
```

Comment: What exactly does "I was not able to run it" mean? Was there any error message? What's the content of `$theContentsOfTheFile`?

Comment: Im finding difficult to execute it

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that there is no `;` at the end of the lines with comments (`#`) in them. Tcl uses either newline or semi-column as a line seperator, and comments are a line by themselves. try using this instead:

```
proc parseFileContents {contents infoVar} { 
    upvar 1 $infoVar inf 
    set lineNum 0 
    foreach line [split $contents "\n"] {  
       incr lineNum;         # Skip comment lines (?) 
       if {[string match {$*} $line]} continue;         # Skip blank lines 
       if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue;        # Parse a "real" line    
       if {[scan $line "%s%s%s%s%s%s%f%f%s%s" a b c name d e value f g h] == 10} {             
           set inf($name) $value
       } else { 
           # Oh dear, didn't work!
           puts "warning: did not understand line $lineNum\n$line"
       }
    } 
}
```

Note that I did not test this new code, only fixed the syntax errors...

Comment: ... except the missing bracket on the `string match` line

Answer (score 2):

Also check that the

```
if {[string match {$*} $line}
```

is missing a closing bracket

```
if {[string match {$*} $line]}
```

The final code should be like that.

```
proc parseFileContents {contents infoVar} { 
    upvar 1 $infoVar inf 
    set lineNum 0 
    foreach line [split $contents "\n"] {  
       incr lineNum;         # Skip comment lines (?) 
       if {[string match {$*} $line]} continue;         # Skip blank lines 
       if {[string trim $line] eq ""} continue;        # Parse a "real" line    
       if {[scan $line "%s%s%s%s%s%s%f%f%s%s" a b c name d e value f g h] == 10} {             
           set inf($name) $value
       } else { 
           # Oh dear, didn't work!
           puts "warning: did not understand line $lineNum\n$line"
       }
    } 
}
```

If still fails put a copy of your content file. Keep in mind that "infoVar" should be the name of an existing array.

Comment: note that the glob pattern `$*` does not match a blank line, it matches a line beginning with a dollar-sign.

Comment: All the comments are shifted. I was simply too lazy to fix them too. Every comment is referencing to the next line

Comment: @Carlos, my comment was really directed toward the asker.

Comment: @Nazeeb, Please add to the case an example of how are you calling the proc, with the variables definitions. And also the result of 'puts $::errorInfo' Otherwise will be quite hard to help you.

Comment: @Nazeeb, if you're doing that, the vcc may be ok, since you're sending the variable name, but vss should be $vss since you want to send the content of the variable.

Comment: @ carlos: How should I call a procedure which is in a file say x.tcl..and which has to extract the contents from other file say Y.tcl